# how to fill one row with an image in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, uitableview, xcode4.5

I'm creating a `UITableView`, containing information about a company. It has multiple sections, and I filled most cells with just a `textlabel` and a `detailtextlabel` through 2-dimensional array's. I want 1 cell (the second cell of the first section to be exact) to be filled with an image.

The first thing that popped up in my mind, was creating another 2-dimensional array, and fill it with empty objects, except for the one image. however, that doesn't make sense and i'm sure there are more professional and logical ways to do this.

So the question is: How do I fill one `tableViewCell` with an image, in a `tableview` with multiple sections. any help would be highly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: as per you question "the second cell of the first section to be exact" in cellForRowAtIndexPath if(indexpath.section == 0 && indexpath.row == 1) {

// create Special Cell

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to create a multidimension array.Just add a check in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of UITableView datasource

```
if(indexpath.section == 0)
```

and set the background image of cell content view or you can also create a new UIImageView and add that in cell as a subview.

Comment: It helped me to identify the reason of getting weird response in table view.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect a few such exceptions, you can create a dictionary of exceptions, where the keys are `NSIndexPath` objects, the values images. Then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` check to see if the dictionary contains the index path. If so, use the image, else go to your array for data.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not uncommon, the only thing to understand now is the delegate methods give you  enough information about the section and the row displayed. Now in those methods you can use your datasource and check for the required conditions and construct/return the cell.

It will be something on these lines:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

// When you get to the section where you want customisation create and return the cell accordingly
if(indexpath.section == 0) {

// create Special Cell

} else {

// Create Normal Cell

}

  return cell;

 }
```

Dont forget to reuse the created cells using `dequecellwithreuseindentifier` method. I am sure you can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==1) {
        UIView *v=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]]];
        cell.backgroundView=v;
    }else{
        UIView *v=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]]];
        cell.backgroundView=v;//OR SET cell.backgroundView=nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use -

```
  (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atable cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

  return cell;

  }
```

I hope, it will help you.

Comment: this would just fill all the cells with one image. I'm afraid @LeoNatan is right.

Comment: Yes Leo, totally agree with you.